# Search very small ultrasound emitter\receiver

Tags: arduino, ultrasound

I am looking for a very small emitter/receiver ultrasound. Not to be confused with the distance meter. The device must be 2 in 1. Switch mode. Or should register a signal if it does not send. Only analogue. Very low power, up to 20 cm. No longer required. Without resonator. Looking for all day I can not find:(.

Comment: Off-topic but also: have you considered that what you're looking for simply **might not exist**? Your requirements seem a but "random" and not well thought through.

Comment: My question is not what it seems and what does not ... If you do not know the topic. Just go on.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why classical transceiver sensors like this one does not fit you?

https://www.murata.com/products/sensor/ultrasonic

Comment: This isn't an answer, it should have been a **comment**.

Comment: Maybe it is, maybe he didn't know that same sensor could transmit and receive.

Comment: @Shiro Thanks, this looks like what I'm looking for. Fools more. They do not know what sound can emit, it can also register its presence.